# What is the correct syntax for SQL Statement using MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax

In access i used this and its works fine:

```
(tblReservations_Dates.Date) Between #" & dteBegDate & "# And #" & dteEndDate & "#
```

Using MySQL I used this:

```
(tblReservations_Dates.Date) Between '" & dteBegDate & "' And '" & dteEndDate & "'
```

However the data is not displayed I was just wondering if this is the correct syntax for SQL Statement for comparing dates?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need the brackets around the table.column reference
2. You need to make sure the query is submitting the start & end values in the proper datattype - date in this case.

Use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to safely convert whatever you're providing into a date datatype for MySQL.  If you provide the date format, I'd be happy to update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make certain that the date strings (dteBegDate and dteEndDate) are in the format expected by MySQL, which would be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. So, right now would be

```
2009-11-25 21:45:52
```

(in Pacific time). Other than that, it should work fine.